# Keep the Javascript Iteration after reload in chrome console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm doing iteration, and in code last code in the iteration i put a code that will reload the page.

How to keep the JavaScript iteration running after reload and continue the state ?

E.g

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    document.reload();
}
```

After running above code, the code stopped and the console reloaded .

The code above might not work, but i wish it explain what i'm trying to do .

Comment: When the page reloads, all the JavaScript is reloaded.  Meaning all variables are deleted.  You can maybe save your state in a cookie (or LocalStorage).

Comment: @karthikr There's several options, don't be so restrictive

Comment: @Ian and the options are ?

Comment: @karthikr `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, cookies, server sessions, `window.name`, query string

Comment: Additionally, you could install Tamermonkey and create a user script with your for loop but this might be overkill.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the state in a place where it's not reset. `localStorage` is the ideal solution.

```
var i = parseInt(localStorage['i'])||0;
localStorage['i'] = i+1;
// do some stuff
// and reload if you want
```

Comment: Although it might make more sense to use `sessionStorage` because it's restricted to the each tab/window, in the case that this page is opened multiple times in the same browser, so they don't conflict :)

Comment: Thank you.  
It keeps the variable's value, but the javascript is stopped isn't ? 
I should manualy continue the console right ?

Comment: Yes, the script is stopped, so you can't have a for loop. I'm not sure of what you mean with "manualy continue the console".

Comment: What @batik meant was to re-execute the script once the page is reloaded

Answer (score 4):

You can use TamperMonkey to accomplish this. TamperMonkey scripts are also reset when reloading the page. However, because they have the ability to store data and are run every time the page loads, you can implement behavior that persists across page reloads. Here is an example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         HttpBin reload
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Reload something a couple of times
// @author       Sjoerd
// @match        https://httpbin.org/get
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var i = GM_getValue('counter', 0);
    GM_setValue('counter', i + 1);

    if (i < 5) {
        location.reload();
    }
})();
```

The [`GM_getValue`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_getValue) and [`GM_setValue`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setValue) functions store data in some Tampermonkey data store, so that it is available the next time the script runs. Note that you need to use the [`@grant`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant) header to use those functions.

We get the value of the counter and increase it by one. Then we reload the page if the counter is less than 5. This reloads the page five times, just like in your example.

After you have run this once, the `counter` value in the Tampermonkey data store is set to 6 and the script won't reload anymore. If you want to reload the page another five times you will have to program something to reset the counter.