# How do I make a loop that continuously reloads the page using Chrome Javascript Console?

Tags: javascript, loops, console, reload

Using the Chrome javascript console, I want to create a loop that reloads the page every 60 seconds, and that will do that 10 times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){document.location.reload()},60*1000);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that once the page is reloaded the loop stops.
I've seen posts saying to check the box to "Preserve log upon navigation" in the console settings, and I have done this, but it doesn't work.

How do I make it so that the script will continue running after the page has been reloaded?

If it's not possible using the chrome javascript console alone, then is there another way to accomplish this that will still allow me to be able to execute other javascript commands in the same loop?

Comment: The console code is attached to the page so when the page reloads, that code stops running.  You can't do it the way you want.   A page can continuously reload itself, but you'd have to put the code for the next reload or meta refresh in the page itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there something else i could use to do this?

Comment: You could make your own local web page with an iframe in it that points to the page you want to reload and then put code in your own page that reloads the iframe over and over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep the console script persistent in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238492/keep-the-console-script-persistent-in-google-chrome)